# Express Gateway JWT issue

Tags: jwt, express-gateway

I'm using express gateway as an API gateway. I want EG (Express Gateway) to authenticate JWTs that my keycloak server will sign. My setup in gateway.config.yml is like this:

```
http:
  port: 6060
admin:
  port: 9876
  hostname: localhost
apiEndpoints:
  api:
    host: localhost
    paths: '/ip'
serviceEndpoints:
  httpbin:
    url: 'https://httpbin.org'
policies:
  - basic-auth
  - jwt
  - cors
  - expression
  - key-auth
  - log
  - oauth2
  - proxy
  - rate-limit
pipelines:
  default:
    apiEndpoints:
      - api
    policies:
    # Uncomment `key-auth:` when instructed to in the Getting Started guide.
      - jwt:
          secretOrPublicKey: MySuperSecretKey
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: httpbin 
              changeOrigin: true
```

I'm starting EG server, and then I'm going to https://jwt.io/ selecting HS256 setting the payload, and secret key and a JWToken is generated. Then I'm making a request with postman using bearer token as it is the default and I'm getting 401 unauthorized.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong with the configuration?

Comment: i am trying to achive the same. i.e Express gateway + keycloak as Identity provider.  is there a guide that you followed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the current configuration you're required to create an internal credential `JWT` credential so that Express Gateway can look for the token and check it accordingly.

In case you want to skip this check, just set the `checkCredentialExistence` to `false` as a `jwt` policy parameter. The request will then pass.

Cheers!

Comment: Yeap, That's the solution. I was going to post the answer to my own question, but you got me first. Thanks @Vincenzo